# How can i edit HTML files in bulk?

Tags: html, text-editors, html5, html-files

I have a website with 35000 pages, I am trying to edit them in bulk using Notepad++  via find in files options but unable to do complete its always going on Not responding so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for a [Python](https://www.python.org) script with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these are just too many files to search? Try to limit the number of files with the (filename) `Filters` input field (like `a*.html` for all files starting with `a`) or uncheck option (find) `In all sub-folders` and apply the search step by step.

Image just one match in each file would produce a search result of 35000 matches in 35000 files!

Answer (score 0):

Not responding is not the same as crashed. Especially in Notepad++ on a large operation, it goes not responding, but is very hard at work, and then suddenly, it responds and all changes have been committed. Verify through Task Manager how much CPU it is consuming. Anything above 5% and its still working, so let it be and it will eventually come back to life.

Do note, that the more complex or more files it has to go through, the longer it can take. Given you mention 35000 files, it is very likely that this may take somewhere between 4 and 8 hours, if not more...

Answer (score 0):

If possible then switch to `Visual Studio Code Editor`. This is much better and faster then Notepad++. You can perform same task in `VS Code`. If you can't switch to VS Code then I would recommend you to please add filter while replacing code via find in files.

> Press CTRL + H. Click on `find in files` tab
>
> You will find field `Filters`. There would be default value `*.*`. You should make it `*.extension`. For Ex:`*.html,*.js,*.css` etc

I hope it will help you. All the Best!